# how to put .properties file in classpath of an Eclipse plug-in

Tags: eclipse, jar, classpath

I have an application which is making use of a .jar file and a .properties file which must reside in the same directory as where the .jar file lies. On a normal java application, this works fine, however I'm building an Eclipse plug-in. I've tried attaching the .properties everywhere, in the classpath, build path, putting them in the same folder and calling the jar file from there (this gives an obsure error) and I've even tried putting the .properties file inside the .jar file even.... but no luck. Any ideas how this could be done please?

Thanks and regards,
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the **FileLocator** class will help you. The FileLocator provides a find method where you can specify the Bundle and a resource to look for.

Ingo